# Magento 1.7.0.2 COD payment option is not visible even its enabled from admin end.

Tags: magento-1.7

I have enabled COD payment option from admin side, but even after that its not visible as an payment option while checkout process.

I have a custom theme implemented, but after switching to default theme its still not visible.

can any one please let me know whats the best possible way to debug this issue.

Thanks,

-Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration scope you are using.

1. Go to `System > Configuration > Payment Methods`
2. Select your store (in default magento it is `Main Website`) as the `configuration scope.` (top left drop-down)
3. Under `Payment Methods tab` select `Cash On Delivery`
4. Remove the tick `Use Default` in-front of the Enabled drop-down.
5. `Enable and save.`

That's it.